# Data Compression and Image Compression Difference

Tags: compression, jpeg

Is there any difference between data compression and image compression when compressing JPEG images?

Comment: What motivated your question?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, image compression *is* data compression...

Comment: Image compression is a *type* of data compression.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're asking.  Data compression is a broad set of techniques, where image compression is a set of techniques optimized for images (both lossy and lossless compression), and JPEG is a particular image compression technique (where the usual JPEG is lossy).

Comment: @michaelPetrotta i was just wondering if there's any difference that's why i ask the question.

Comment: i'm trying to watermark JPEG images for my project and i want the watermark to be robust against image compression. that's why i wanted to know if there's a difference between the two. thanks for all of your answers

Answer (score 2):

(to 'standardize' your question: I assume with "data compression" you mean general data file compression - in likes of .zip and .rar)
There is a "big" difference:

Data compression is "Lossless" compression - wherein you cannot afford loosing/mistaking even a single bit. Whereas..

Image compression is a "Lossy" compression - wherein you **can** afford to loose/mistake a certain amount of detail depending on you requirement of data-size over quality(data-reproduction). i.e. Your compressed version will not be the exact copy of your original image file; but in data compression - the compressed version will recreate the input file - **exactly**.

Answer (score 0):

JPEG transforms RGB color space to YCbCr color space. Most of the image data is in Y channel and to avoid loss of information, it can be less compressed. But the Cb and Cr channels have color information and is mostly repetitive. This can be easily compressed.

http://nboddula.blogspot.com/2013/05/image-compression-how-jpeg-works.html